# Reference integrity in BinaryFormatter

Tags: c#, reference, protobuf-net, binaryformatter

The existence of AsReference option in Protobuf-net and the word that BinaryFormatter is a "graph serializer" lead me to assume that BinaryFormatter does not maintain references and that it makes a copy of every object.

But I did some tests and found out that all references in a single BinaryFormatter Serialize() or Deserialize() call are maintained even for recursive referencing.

Can I confirm that BinaryFormatter does indeed maintain references? How is this different from Protobuf-net? Seems like I understand "graph serialization" incorrectly? What else should I look out for?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

tl;dr; version - `BinaryFormatter` always preserves references.

The fact that `BinaryFormatter` is a "graph serializer" is synonymous with "it preserves references", since that is *required* to accurately reproduce a graph. The alternative is a ***tree*** serializer (which is *most* of them; `XmlSerializer`, `DataContractSerializer` (without a particular option enabled), `JavascriptSerializer` and protobuf-net without `AsReference` are all tree-based). Tree serializers do *not* generally preserve references (unless they work some tricks, i.e. what `DataContractSerializer` does if you enable full-graph mode, or protobuf-net does with `AsReference`). Tree serializers (without voodoo enabled) tend to explode in a mess with a recursive model, which makes them easy to spot.